# Unable to scrape audio for webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape audio(under experience the sound) from 'https://www.akrapovic.com/en/car/product/16722/Ferrari/488-GTB-488-Spider/Slip-On-Line-Titanium?brandId=20&modelId=785&yearId=5447'. I have written following code but it gives me error.

```
driver.get('https://www.akrapovic.com/en/car/product/16722/Ferrari/488-GTB-488-Spider/Slip-On-Line-Titanium?brandId=20&modelId=785&yearId=5447')
audio_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="container-xl"]')
print(audio_link.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'audio'))
```

Hope to find a better way to scrape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//audio')
```